# Negative z-index knocking out links

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

I'm trying to add a sidebar to my page.  The main body container on the page has a box-shadow, so I want the sidebar to appear as though it's coming out from underneath the container so the shadow will be on top of it.  I made my sidebar div a direct child of the body container (which has position: relative), and set it's position to absolute, then positioned it using the top and right position values.  I got it in the right place, then applied a negative z-index so that it would be under the body.  The problem is, this is making any links that I put in the sidebar unclickable in all but IE9.  I don't know how else I can accomplish this without knocking out the links.  Any ideas?

I would post a link to a page showing an example, but I'm actively making changes to it, so by the time you clicked it you probably wouldn't see what I'm going for.  I'll try to explain better.

The body container is 720px wide and has an auto margin so that it appears centered in the page.  It is positioned relative.

The sidebar is a direct child (the first child) of the body container.  It has a fixed width, position absolute, padding, etc. and has a top and right position applied, along with a z-index of -100.

Here's a link:

http://reachchallenges.infectionist.com

Comment: I don't think this question can't be answered without a) a live example b) some source code or preferably c) a jsfiddle example where the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: Does your body container extend over the the entire sidebar?

Comment: The body doesn't cover the sidebar visually, but when I look at it in Chrome's Developer Tools, the margin causes it to cover the whole page.  I'll edit the post with a link and just not work on it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the negative `z-index` and give an [inner shadow](http://sublimeorange.com/css/css3-inner-shadow/) to the sidebar that is the same as the outer shadow of the `.body` element.

You´d have to try it to see how it affects the border of the sidebar.

Comment: I thought of that, and there are a few problems.  First, it's very difficult to get an inner shadow to look the same as an outer one, I tried.  Second, the shadow would be locked to the right edge of the sidebar, so when I animate it in and out you'd be able to see it moving.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what effect is desired but maybe this barebones fiddle can give some hints as for how to approach problems of such kind.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65u1o78v/)

The way to get links to work is to toggle z-index back to a positive number. Your CSS will look like:

```
.z-index1{
    z-index: 1 !important;
}
```

and your JS should be:

```
$("#div-on-top").click(function(){
    $("#div-on-bottom").toggleClass("margin");
    $("#div-on-bottom").toggleClass("z-index1");
});
```

Clicking on `#div-on-top` will move it out of the way revealing `#div-on-bottom` and it will also bring `#div-on-bottom` to the top, making links clickable.

I also applied shadow to the `#div-on-top` and it looked ok (to me; see jsfiddle).

Comment: though it seems like I am 4 years late